# Google-ads DFP multiple ad-sizes gives failure

Tags: android, request, admob, google-dfp

I am trying to implement multiple ad sizes with google ads DFP as is described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner#multiple_ad_sizes)

But the weird thing is, that if I use a single ad size as shown in the code below, it works:

```
 _adView = new PublisherAdView(activity);
    _adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER);
```

But if I use multiple ads, in an equal way as described in the documentation, shown below, the request fails:

```
 _adView = new PublisherAdView(activity);
    _adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER, new AdSize(120, 20), new AdSize(250, 250));
```

So the first snippet works and gives ads, while the second gives the following in the logcat:

```
12-07 12:17:17.082  30786-30786/app.myappname.nl I/Ads﹕ Ad opening.
12-07 12:17:17.109  30786-30812/app.myappname.nl W/Ads﹕ The ad response must specify one of the supported ad sizes.
12-07 12:17:17.167  30786-30786/app.myappname.nl I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
12-07 12:17:17.167  30786-30786/app.myappname.nl W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

I have also tried using only standard ad sizes, but this does not make any difference. Does anyone knows why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened because I had added my device as a test device to get Google test advertisements.

```
final PublisherAdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("BBE743F18R0143D88563501D114CF633")
```

After removing the testDevice line and using real ads I could send the array of sizes to request an ad.